# How to send HTML mail in PHP on Linux

Tags: php, linux, email

I have to written the following code to send a mail using PHP in my website, which is hosted on a Linux server. The mail is sent, but the message is sent as raw HTML instead of markup text. Here's the code:

```
<?php
sendMail('name@domain.tld', 'Your recovered password', 'Your password is <b>ABC123</b>', 'kush.impetus@gmail.com');

function sendMail($from='name@domain.tld', $subject, $message, $to = 'name@domain.tld'){
    $message = '<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>'.$subject.'</title>
        </head>
        <body>'.$message.'</body>
        </html>';
    $message = preg_replace("#(?<!\r)\n#si", "\r\n", $message); 
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);  

    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    $headers[] = "From: $from";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: $from";
    $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";

    $additional_params = "-f $from -r $from";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers)))
        echo 'Mail Sent';
    else
        echo 'Mail NOT Sent';
    exit();
}
```

?>

How do I correct the code to send the HTML mail correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My first gut reaction is to change Content-type from text/plain to text/html.

Comment: The content type is text/plain?

Comment: @KingSkippus: Thanks King. The problem was I had used Content-type in header declaration as text/plain. Changing to text/html worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
```

to

```
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

This way you tell your mail program that it's HTML and not a plain text.